# QGIS SCP Error When Classifying Landsat 5

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, classification, scp

Good day! I am trying to classify a landsat 5 collection 2 level 2 image of my study area, but when I start the classification process after selecting the ROIs an error occurs. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment. I am using QGIS version 3.28.11 and SCP version 8.1.6 and I have tried redownloading the bands and using different satellite images, but the same error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/user/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 143, in run_classification_action
    run_classifier()
  File "C:\Users/user/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 487, in run_classifier
    if output is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment
```

What can be done so that this error can be prevented?